# Rust printpdf How to Add Link Elements

Tags: pdf, rust

I am using printpdf for my project. I want to add Link Elements that has hyperlinks in them. I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.rs/printpdf/latest/printpdf/) but I couldn't see any way I can embed links within text. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It might not support it yet. I see you already opened a feature request about it on their repository, but I see you've already [done that](https://github.com/fschutt/printpdf/issues/148) ;) So I'm not sure what to add here.